# How to extract values from a text file using a script?

Tags: regex, shell, unix, text, text-manipulation

If I have a file with the contents as below:

```
field1=value1,field2=value2,field3=value3,field4=value4,field5=value5,..;(new line)
field1=value1.1,field2=value1.2,field3=value1.3,field4=value1.4,field5=value1.5,...; (new line)
.....
....
...
```

Each line ends with semi-colon and a new line character.

How can I extract and store(or display) in the below format?

[image]

Comment: That will be possible, but in which format/language do you want the output??

Comment: probably store it in an excel file or a text file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");


  foreach (string line in lines)
        {
           String[] Contain=line.Split(",");
             foreach (string ordata in Contain)
             {
                  String[] data=ordata.Split("=");
                  var Value=data[1];
               // Write Code for store Data
              }
        }
```

above code helps you to make it working.